# Is it possible to access the css class using webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I want to get the background image url which is defined in a css class . Is it possible to do by using selenium webdriver

Example :

Sample Text with Logo

Now I want to achevie the logo url but that url is defined in the title class.
If any solved these type of issues please let me know

Comment: you want to get logo URL OR logo background image URL?

Comment: Logo background image url , but that is defined in the class "title" in a seperate css file

Comment: Yes but which css property it is using for background?  background OR background-image

Comment: css property name is :: background

Comment: ok kindly check my answer..Hope that help.

Comment: My requirement is same as the question asked. I tried the solution but it is not working. HTML: <div class="apply-nav-height" id="etsy-logo"> <a href="/in-en/?ref=lgo">Etsy</a> </div> CSS class: .gnav-header #etsy-logo a { background: url("/assets/dist/images/etsylogo.20150529203416.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto transparent; color: #f45800; display: block; height: 100%; margin-top: 2px; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -10000em; width: 100%; } and I want to retrieve background

Comment: HTML:<div class="apply-nav-height" id="etsy-logo">
            <a href="/in-en/?ref=lgo">Etsy</a>
        </div>

Comment: This question is answered and accepted, doesnt .getCssValue("background") work for you? Please ask a new question instead, also add what you have tried until now.

Comment: Use below code 
String imgurl = driver.findElement(By.id('etsylogo')).getCssValue("background");

Comment: Let me know it is worked for you or not

Comment: Hi @manjusha - welcome to SQA - I've converted your answer to a comment on the original question, but I agree with Niels that you may want to just ask this as a separate question if the answer given isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get property background URL by following code `.getCssValue("background")`

Example:

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("your site URL");
String url = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//path")).getCssValue("background")
System.out.println(url);
```

Above will print background Image URL as per your need. Please replace actual URL and your title div xpath in above code.

Comment: Great..cheers..:) Any time I am here to help ...:)